# Android: is there another way for js calling native, besides using addJsInterface & onJsPrompt?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

Android WebView offered addJsInterface to be a js-native-bridge, however it's broken ever since Android 2.3 if memory served me. Some smart guy found a workaround by overriding onJsPrompt. I'm curious if there's another way to make js call native inside webview, besides these two. Thanks.

Comment: There's this JS engine, called rhino. Maybe you can use it.

Comment: @Mighter, sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I don't want to include an entire JS engine, like rhino, v8, to run js scripts. I'm just seeking a new way to make js-native-bridge in WebView.

Comment: If so, you can grab webview sources and construct your own bridge.